# Cant create an Azure Web App Bot because of Resource Provider Registration Error

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-storage, azure-bot-service

I am trying to create a bot on Azure. When I go to Home > Bot Services > Bot Service > Web App Bot > Web App Bot, and type in all of the information for my bot and click create I get an error saying "Resource provider 'Microsoft.Storage' not registered for the subscription". You can see this in the images below. [image] [image] I looked around for answers for a while and it seemed like I had to do what run the command `PS Azure:\> Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage`. After that, when I ran `PS Azure:\> Get-AzureRmResourceProvider -ListAvailable | Select-Object ProviderNamespace, RegistrationState` to view its registration status it said "Registering" (see image below). [image] However, to my understanding it is only supposed to take a few minutes to register and I ran this command yesterday and it still says "Registering" for me. Does anyone have any suggestions for things that I can try to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately a subset of customers were experiencing issues with storage due to a capacity issue. I can not say for certain at this moment that the capacity issue is affecting your ability to register with the resource provider but it does seem consistent. 
Could you check again(Rerun the below command) since it should have been resolved by now ?

```
Register-AzResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage
```

Comment: It is finally registered. Thank you for explaining why it might have been taking so long.